# Tomcat run configuration in intellij idea takes a long time to start

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using Apache Tomcat run configuration in Intellij IDEA to debug my webapp.

It takes about 2 minutes for following output (tomcat startup output) to come up in output window.

```
D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\bin\catalina.bat run
[2019-08-21 08:43:12,885] Artifact my-webapp:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\myusername\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_my_webapp_3"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.24"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

I had used to debug this same app some time ago, but there was no slowness like this back then. What could be the reason for this. Any ideas to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you face the same issue with new sample projects? Do you use any antivirus software?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the existing run configuration and created a new one. Then it became faster again.